# typeerror: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout' pymongo

Tags: linux, python-2.7, pymongo, rhel

I'm trying to extract the facebook data into mongoDB. I'm using python 2.7.3 and pymongo-3.3.0 on the linux environment (RHEL), while extracting the data, I got the following error.

> `Exception AttributeError: "'Cursor' object has no attribute '_Cursor__id'" in <bound method Cursor.__del__ of <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x48fa110>> ignored
>   (<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>, TypeError("__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'",),<traceback object at 0x490a638>)`

Please suggest me how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue while using collection.find() and the parameter to use is **not** "*timeout*".

The **correct parameter is** "*no_cursor_timeout*". This parameter will avoid the exception on cursor timeout.

Example of usage:

```
collection.find(no_cursor_timeout=True)
```

This will avoid your (probably) original exception:

```
pymongo.errors.CursorNotFound: Cursor not found, cursor id:
```

PD: I will update my answer if you are not using the find on collection. In case this is not helpful please update your question with an example os usage.